# Problem with putting other language content in "RichTextField"?

Tags: core-service, cme

I have created a component and entered the content in  "RichTextField" using the Core service. Component is successfully created but when i open this in "SDL Tridion" GUI. I found that all the Japanese language text into this field  replaced with '?' characters. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can your client OS support Japanese characters? I have no problems with doing this on my server.

Comment: Are you sure you have support for Japanease, may be you can copy-paste the japanease text in Notepad to verify

Comment: You've tagged the question with "core service" and "content delivery". Can you edit your question with more details to clarify this? E.g. Are you inserting the RTF Japanese via core service and see the question marks once you've published the content, or something else?

Comment: Start with the basics and try copy/pasting Japanese content using the CME. If that works, then you know that it is _for sure_ your CoreService app that is not keeping the encoding. If that doesn't work, then it's likely a Server setting.

Comment: @Nuno when i copy/paste Japanese content using "SDL Tridion" GUI it is working.but using "CoreService" it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nuno has also mentioned about the support for Japanese in the OS, you may also want to check below things additionally as you question is not quite clear:

- Try to do through CME, if it is working then ensure you have setup UTF-8 support for it in the Web Config.
- You may also want to check for the Collation of SQL Server - whether it has not been tempered with and support for Unicode characters

**UPDATe:**

You can try something like this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization
           fileEncoding="utf-8"
           requestEncoding="utf-8"
           responseEncoding="utf-8"
           culture="en-US"
           uiCulture="de-DE"
        />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The path of the web.config should be:

```
/<Installed Path>/Tridion/webservices/web.config
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer Pankaj. Seems like a comment asking for additional details in the question.

Comment: Pankaj I found there are many web config files in tridion folder,in which web config file should I setup UTF-8 support.

Comment: The one meant for the Core Service

Comment: @Nick: Updated the Answer

Comment: @Pankaj can u provide a sample code of configuration in web application and location of the web config file

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: @Pankaj thanks my problem solved using utf-8 encoding all the Japanese character are successfully showing in SDL Tridion but now when the page publish on the IIS server after this when i opened publish page on the browser and notepad  i found only question mark and no Japanese character  .Why is this happening.

Comment: The same thing applies for your CD and/or presentation server as well. Ensure, the same setting is there in the web.config of your application for which you are publishing and opening the page.

Answer (score 3):

This is normally because the given (Non-English) **language pack is not installed** on the server or on your (client) machine.

**Or, it may be that your browser is not configured to use the correct character encoding**.

You can find out more information about installing the correct language pack from Microsoft here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/language-packs

In addition, the screenshot below shows that I am using the Unicode (UFT-8) character encoding within Chrome. You could try changing this to `Auto Detect`.

[image]

You may also want to look at the answers to [Why do I always see boxes instead of Japanese text?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/AV9F04IQmFA) (in particular, mushimushi's one about downloading the Japanese language pack) and [Resolve - Japanese fonts for Google Chrome and more!](http://rinatsu.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/resolve-japanese-fonts-for-google.html)